# IDE autocomplete for pytorch

Tags: autocomplete, ide, pytorch

I'm using Visual Studio Code. Recently tried out Kite. Both of which doesn't seem to have autocomplete for pytorch.

Is is possible with these tools ? If not, can someone suggest an editor that does ?

Thank you!

Comment: [Kite](https://www.kite.com/) works well for me in Spyder 5.0.3 via Anaconda and has support for VS Code, PyCharm, Spyder, Atom, Vim, JupyterLab, etc. I also added `torch` to the list of preloaded modules under Tools --> Preferences --> Completion and Linting --> Introspection --> Advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ 
Get Community version, because it is free with debugger and autocomplete. (more than enough for student)

To get autocomplete and run/debug the code on Pycharm IDE, you have to set correct project interpreter path to your environment (or virtual environment) which you install pytorch

The screenshot shows that I set Project Interpreter path to conda environment named 'pytorch', which I install Pytorch. 
[image]

Comment: autocomplete doesn't work for pytorch even though its in the list

Comment: @StepanYakovenko it work for me. You must install pytorch and select the correct environment (which have pytorch installed) so Pycharm can scan for package and autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder does autocomplete for PyTorch as well

Answer (score 0):

Both Spyder and PyCharm have auto-complete feature for the installed libraries. But this feature does not seem to work for the local project files (functions, classes, variables defined in the local files even if they are imported).

They also have "go to definition" and "help", but again, only for the installed libraries.

I hope these features will be included soon, in addition to "references to this variable/function/class", which is available in advanced IDEs and is quite useful.

Comment: if you import correctly, pycharm should be able to auto-complete function in your own file. Mind the directory when import. for python 3, in same directory, " import .myfile  (must have a dot . for local location)