# PyTorch autocomplete (code completion) in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3, pytorch, code-completion

I'm a fan of Sublime Text 3 and would like to get code autocompletion for PyTorch. However, I can't get this working yet. Any suggestions or starting points where I can begin to get this working?

I have searched in the packages repository of Sublime Text but unfortunately there's none.

Note: I have looked at a related question here [IDE autocomplete for pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287476/ide-autocomplete-for-pytorch) but that's only for VS Code.

Comment: So why not switch to VS Code :)

Comment: VS Code is painfully slow, that's probably why.

Answer (score 4):

Not a sublime user, but [Jedi autocompletion](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) handles PyTorch suggestions just fine.

Jedi is an autocompletion engine and **should** work for any Python package, including the ones in virtual environment if you set it up and including PyTorch/Tensorflow.

Anyway, [sublime version](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion) seems to be missing a few things like results caching, hence you may have to wait a few seconds after issuing `torch.` (library is quite heavy, that's why you most probably will experience some lag). If you'd like to speed it up, I see no other possibility than changing it manually (vim plugin for jedi I am using has this option implemented, you may check how they've done it [here](https://github.com/zchee/deoplete-jedi), both  jedi plugins seem to be written in Python hence should be tunable/fixable).

Oh, and if something isn't working (or maybe you would like to submit a PR request to jedi team/sublime jedi team), the community around it is quite vibrant and you should get some help (definitely better and more in-depth than here on StackOverflow).